# Can I automatically remove a parameter on querystring with Request.Url.Query?

Tags: c#, .net

When I get the querystring with `Request.Url.Query` I'd like to exclude a parameter (without using replace, or function like these).

So, for example, if I have this querystring :

```
?ID=1241&IDL=241&HC=1241
```

I'd like to exclude `IDL` getting :

```
?ID=1241&HC=1241
```

Is this a implemented way or I need to make my own function?

EDIT : I care about the order of my query string values.

Comment: Do you mean replace the Query property in the Uri object to "fool downstream" or just getting a string not including it?

Comment: not including it...! Also because I don't know what do you mean with "fool downstream" :)

Comment: @markzzz I think he means "do you want other calls of `Request.Url.Query` later on to beleive that the query string value isn't there?"

Comment: The querystring cannot be modified. but you can parse it (it's a KeyValuePair collection) and modify the collection, and then restore it back (via a Response.Redirect("page.aspx?" + modifiedQS))

Comment: @Oxonhammer : can you give an example? I'd like to remove this parameter, then get the string without that parameter :)

Comment: @vcsjones : I don't want to edit the object, just get a different string :)

Comment: Request.QueryString is a collection. use it build up a new string. Or do what @vscjones suggests below?

Comment: What do you mean by, automatically?

Comment: on a side note, caring about the *order* of query string params doesn't sound right to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still string manipulation, but how about something like:

```
String.Concat("?",
    String.Join("&",
        Request.Url.Query.Substring(1)
            .Split('&')
            .Where(k => !k.StartsWith("IDL="))
            .ToArray() // For .NET versions prior to v4.0
     )
)
```

Alternatively you could use `Request.QueryString` to get at a processed collection of query-string parameters.

**EDIT:** This will leave your parameters in the order they were sent.

Here's a sample ASPX page that outputs a modified query-string (I've tested it in a ASP.NET 3.5 Web-Site):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Query String Removal</title>
</head>
<body>
    Modified query-string: <%=
        String.Concat("?",
            String.Join("&",
                Request.Url.Query.Substring(1)
                    .Split('&')
                    .Where(k => !k.StartsWith("IDL="))
                    .ToArray() // For .NET versions prior to v4.0
             )
        )
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** `System.Linq` has been imported. An exception will be raised if you don't specify a query-string.

Comment: And from this can I remove directly a parameter?

Comment: I take it you mean from the `Request.QueryString` collection, I'm afraid not, it's a read-only collection :-[, as mentioned by Oxonhammer.

Comment: added (string[]) before `Request.Url.Query....`, but now it says `System.InvalidCastException: Impossibile eseguire il cast di oggetti di tipo 'WhereArrayIterator`1[System.String]' sul tipo 'System.String[]'.`

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? The code I posted I tried in a .NET ASP.NET web-site.

Comment: ^^ .NET 4.0 ASP.NET web-site. I've tweaked the code for prior versions of .NET, I haven't tested it though.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I used this which can be called multiple times if you have a list of keys that you want removed from the querystring if they exists:

```
private string RemoveQueryStringItemWithKeyName(string url, string keyName)
{
    var urlItemRemoved = String.Join("&", url.Split('&').Where(k => !k.StartsWith(keyName + "=")));
    return urlItemRemoved;
}
```